# Why is glTexSubImage2D giving me GL_INVALID_OPERATION here?

Tags: c++11, opengl

I've been banging at this for more than a few hours now.  I can't figure out why `glTexSubImage2D` is an invalid operation in this code.

```
    GLuint texture = 0;
    int textureWidth = 512;
    int textureHeight = 512;

    // Create and bind
    glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Set wrapping and filtering.
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // Set storage type and allocate memory.
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32UI, textureWidth, textureHeight);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

I've queried a bunch of parameters (most against mipmap level 0) on my texture before calling `glTexSubImage2D`, and all the results seem to indicate that the texture is well-formed:

```
GL_TEXTURE_IMMUTABLE_FORMAT: 1
GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH: 512
GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT: 512
GL_TEXTURE_DEPTH: 1
GL_TEXTURE_INTERNAL_FORMAT: 33334
GL_TEXTURE_RED_SIZE: 32
GL_TEXTURE_GREEN_SIZE: 0
GL_TEXTURE_BLUE_SIZE: 0
GL_TEXTURE_ALPHA_SIZE: 0
GL_TEXTURE_DEPTH_SIZE: 0
GL_TEXTURE_COMPRESSED: 0
GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_OFFSET: 0
```

I've also tried setting actual data instead of `NULL` via a single-dimension vector array:

```
std::vector<GLuint> textureData(textureWidth * textureHeight, 0);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, textureData.data());
```

And through `memcpy`:

```
GLuint *zeros = new GLuint[textureWidth * textureHeight];
memset(zeros, 0, textureWidth * textureHeight * 4);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, zeros);
delete[] zeros;
```

None of this changes the error.  In my fragment shader I (obviously) find a black texture.

Comment: `GL_RED` is not a valid format for an `GL_R32UI` internal format, you'll have to use `GL_RED_INTEGER`. However, using `NULL` as the data pointer will then just crash, unless you have a PBO bound.

Comment: @derhass Oh man, thank you so much!  I don't know how I stared at this so long and missed that!  If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: That's nice that this was marked as a duplicate, but I searched stack overflow extensively before posting my issue, and that answer never popped up... I would have only known to search for it in retrospect.